# How could I generate the time format "2015-11-29T00:00:00.000Z" from datetime object

Tags: python

Suppose I have a datatime object, how could I convert it with the kind of string format

```
2015-11-29T00:00:00.000Z
```

I don't know what's the name of the type's datetime string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.isoformat()` on a datetime object to get a string in that format.

The format itself is called the ISO 8601 format / representation for dates and times.

Comment: With three decimal places for seconds and the trailing `Z` for zulu time? I don't think so. If the exact format requested by the OP can be achieved in the standard library without custom `strftime()` formatting, I'd love to hear about it.